# What is the proper way to suggest features to be added to the C# language?

Tags: c#

What is the proper way to suggest features to be added to the C# language?

For example, I would like to have an operator similar to `??` but for selecting the min or max values.

I'd like `a <? b` to expand to `a < b ? a : b`
likewise for `>?`

Comment: Contact the team responsible for the language at Microsoft.

Comment: Is there something wrong with using the [Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.min.aspx) or [Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max.aspx) functions?

Comment: Good luck getting this feature added...

Comment: While I didn't intend this question to be about the relevance of this specific feature request. I like it because it could support any class that overloads < instead of the limited selection of overloads for the Math.Min and Math.Max functions. Also it is cleaner for 3 or more. Math.Min(a, Math.Min(b, c)) vs a <? b <? c.

Comment: @Josh - I don't think its a bad idea. I just think that they will shoot it down for a more popular requests. This means it will most likely never be added in the lifetime of C#.

Comment: If C# supported some form of syntactic macros, you could easily add this yourself. Alas... If you really want to experiment with these kinds of language features, have a look at [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/About/) or [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/)

Comment: By the way F# can easily supports this feature: `let inline (<?) (a:^t) (b:^t) = if a < b then a else b`

Comment: **ping Jon Skeet** :) I agree with Matthieu, but couldn't resist giving an alternative answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) is the central Hub regarding all suggestions about Microsoft products.

Concerning Visual Studio and the .NET ecosystem, you will have to go through the "Visual Studio and .Net Framework" product and you will end up on the [Visual Studio User Voice website](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) where ideas can be submitted. You can also find discussions and issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet), for the open-sourced version of .NET.

There is also a [new Q/A site for both Visual Studio and TFS](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/visual-studio-ide.html).

Concerning C#, now that roslyn is open-source, the evolution of C# is discussed in the open, and is still designed by the C# Language Design Team (LDT). You can request and discuss new features of C# on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang).

Comment: Roslyn is open-source. But the C# language specification it adheres to is not open source. It is designed by committee.

Comment: @ArTs adjusted the answer with info, and better formulation.